# Proxy settings for access to the central repository

Tags: java, maven, repository

Tell me please what port I need to open in Windows to granted access to maven central repository? (I am using a proxy)

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/

Comment: Don't configure that in the system settings.xml better is to use the user settings.xml in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to configure the information for the [proxy](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) in your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` like this:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>....</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

Which port/server etc. you have to use no one can say that except your administration department.